# Xrm.Navigation.openUrl issue in Dynamics crm 365 v9.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I have been working with Dynamics 365 v9.0 and I have been facing this issue when I am opening a URL on Dynamics crm 365 web using `Xrm.Navigation.openUrl`, the URL gets opened in new window, But in "UI Interface", it is opening in new tab.

Does anybody help me for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is what it is. I would say, at least MS gave a supported way to open external url compared to `window.open()`. It's in early stage, expecting more parameters in future for [openUrlOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openurl).

```
var url = "http://google.com";
    var openUrlOptions = {
        height: 400,
        width: 800
    };

    Xrm.Navigation.openUrl(url, openUrlOptions);
```

For now, try some browser settings like below for workaround.

[image]

We are also facing behavioral discrepancy with Unified interface compared to classic.

If you are opening Entity Form or Web resource, try `Xrm.Navigation.openForm` or `Xrm.Navigation.openWebResource` which has boolean property `openInNewWindow` under `entityFormOptions` & `windowOptions` parameter respectively.

[Read more](https://bettercrm.blog/2017/10/29/dynamics-365-9-0-client-side-navigation/)

Answer (score 0):

The only way that worked for me in 2020 :) was using window.open and providing Width/Height params.